# Как записать массив структур в файл

Tags: c, файлы

Допустим, у меня есть структура *NameStruct* в которую входит типы char, int, float. И создан массив *MasStruct[10]*

Этот массив храниться в оперативной памяти.

Как я могу записать этот массив в файл? Вот просто и лаконично. Мне не важно, как будет выглядеть файл, если его открыть в редакторе.

Товарищи говорят, что самый просто вариант, это парсить все это дело.

Но так ли дело?

Спасибо заранее за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если структура такая - именно `char`, а не `char*` -

```
struct NameStruct
{
    char c;
    int i;
    float f;
};
```

то я бы делал примерно так:

```
struct NameStruct MasStruct[10];

FILE * f = fopen("filename","wb");
fwrite(MasStruct,sizeof(MasStruct[0]),10,f);
fclose(f);
```

Comment: Благодарю!! А вот допустим, у меня создался filename, он получается будет с расширением .dat???

Comment: И еще одно. Могу ли я теперь, считать этот файл и занести его значения в новый массив этой же структуры????

Comment: Если вы дадите ему такое имя - типа `fopen("filename.dat","wb")`. Сами по себе расширения не добавляются...

Comment: Если структура такая, как я написал - т.е. в ней не строка, а именно `char` - то на том же компиляторе с теми же настройками выравнивания - да. `fread(MasStruct,sizeof(MasStruct[0]),10,f);`. Ну и, понятно, я набросал скелет, а нужно проверять все ошибки - открылся ли файл, записано ли там именно 10 структур и т.д...

Comment: Пардон. Ошибся. Там не просто char, а char[10] и так 3 раза. т.е. дефакто массив char. Будет это так же работать?

Comment: Если статический массив (типа `struct NameStruct
{
    char c[10];`) - да. Если указатель (`char*`) - нет.

Comment: truct Games{
 char Name[20]; // Nazvanie
 char Genre[10]; // Janr
 char Publisher[20]; //Izdatel
 int Date; // God vipuska
 float Price; // Cena igri
} MyGames[10];

Вот примерно так выглядит моя структура. Я думаю он подходит

Comment: запись и считывание проходит отлично, но теперь столкнулся с другой проблемой. Допустим, у меня в массиве 10 элементов (MasStruct[10]), но заполнил я только 3.

Comment: Ну запишите 3...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57696/discussion-between-frip-and-harry).

Comment: Тут нечего обсуждать. `fwrite(MasStruct,sizeof(MasStruct[0]),N,f);`, где N - количество записей.

Comment: изначально это N неизвестно. В этом то и дело. Как бы в программе допустим, есть 2 пункта. Первый - ввод данных. Тут все легко. А второй пункт, допустим, чтение из файла, но мы же не знаем, сколько действительно ячеек заполнено. Ибо данные из структуры выводятся в табличной форме. следовательно, если мы укажем максимальное N. Получится такой случай, что наши данные будут выведены верно, но помимо этого, будут еще пустые строки в таблице.

Comment: Ну читайте, например, поочередно по одной записи. `fread` возвращает количество считанных записей. Как увидите, что больше ничего не считалось - вернуло 0 - значит, все, все записи считаны. Послушайте, откровенно говоря, вы уже хотите совсем не того, о чем спрашивали, а на выполнение всей работы за вас я не подписывался :) Почитайте, как работают `fread/fwrite`, разберётесь...

Comment: решил проблему, используя функцию 'fileno()'. Спасибо вам за помощь в моём вопросе. Очень сильно помогли, респект!